# "Vossa majestade" ou "Vossa senhoria" concordam em gênero com o interlocutor?

Tags: concordância, gendered-speech

- Estou a me dirigir à rainha: "Vossa majestade gostaria de ser acordada mais cedo?"
- Dirijo-me então ao rei: "Vossa majestade gostaria de ser acordado/a mais cedo?

Tenho uma audiência marcada com D. Manuel I e não gostaria de cometer uma gafe, daí a minha pergunta: qual a forma correta quando o interlocutor é um homem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deve-se fazer a concordância do genero conforme o gênero da pessoa que está se dirigindo:

> As expressões “Vossa Senhoria”, “Vossa Excelência” e “Vossa Majestade”
>   são todas elas femininas, por causa do núcleo feminino “Senhoria”,
>   “Excelência” e “Majestade”.
>
> No entanto, em conversa com um juiz, não se diz “Vossa Excelência foi
>   rigorosa”.Em tal circunstância, não se faz a concordância com a
>   palavra, mas sim com a imagem de homem do interlocutor:
>
> Vossa Excelência, Senhor Juiz, foi muito rigoroso na observância da
>   lei.

Fonte: [jurisway](https://www.jurisway.org.br/v2/pergunta.asp?idmodelo=6718)

A mesma recomendação é encontrada aqui:

> Concordância de gênero: faz-se a concordância com o sexo das pessoas a
>   que se referem. Ex: Vossa Senhoria está sendo convidado a assistir a
>   nova palestra no senado. Vossa Excelência será informada das demais
>   alterações.

Fonte: [Tudo Estudo](https://www.todoestudo.com.br/portugues/pronomes-de-tratamento)

Comment: "Vossa Excelência, Senhor Juiz, foi muito rigoroso na observância da lei." - e o juiz responde: "Ri-go-ro-sís-si-ma, querido, ri-go-ro-síííís-si-ma"...

Comment: Parece-me que em Castelhano a concordância não é feita com o sexo da pessoa e sim com o título.